# How you handle on resume scenarios in deep-link plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking

Observation:

1. When an app starts ondevice ready event fires, then user kills the app.
   If user clicks on a apps link , the plugin opens the app properly and goes to the respective page.(Here onDevice ready will trigger and the deeplink observable serves the incoming deeplink).
2. After step 1 When the app is switched, on pause triggers, now user clicks on an app link from gmail, here plugin opens the app, and the "onResume" event is called.
   Question: Will the same ondeviceready .subscribe() will serve the same scenario ?? In my case it doesn't happen . And it never works on all subsequent pause/resume(flip app and comeback to app again).

To handle this I have added the same call on onResume block :

```
        $cordovaDeeplinks.route({
            '#/home/xyz': {
                target: 'xyz',
                parent: 'home'
            }
        }).subscribe(
            function(match) {
            }, function (nomatch) {       //Since my url doesn't match, i am handling the navigation on nomatch.                        
                var loc = nomatch.$link.fragment;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $location.path(loc);
                });
            }
        );
```

So to summarize I have deeplink route logic both in ondeviceready and onresume call.

And it worked for all the scenario, except: the on the first onresume call, if the ondeviceready deeplink is consumed already.

1. an app starts, ondevice ready event fires, then user kills the app.
2. user clicked a link from Gmail and app opened.
3. Now switch the app and click the link again - failed----(this is the only case where it fails)
4. Repeat the step-3 -passed - Worked fine
5. Repeat the step-3 - passed - Worked fine

Debugging further, following is finding:

On device ready : The observer on my app , is called before the deeplink object is created on plugin

On Resume : The observer on my app is called after the deeplink object is created on plugin .

To fix this, now I have changed my ondevice ready code as below and removed the deeplink code from onresume.

```
  //outside onready
  function subscribe_deeplink() {
       $cordovaDeeplinks.route({
            '#/home/xyz': {
                target: 'xyz',
                parent: 'home'
            }
        }).subscribe(
            function(match) {
            }, function (nomatch) {
                $rootScope.isNavigated = true;
                var loc = nomatch.$link.fragment;
                subscribe_deeplink();
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $location.path(loc);
                });
            }
        );
    }

   //inside onready
     $cordovaDeeplinks.route({
            '#/home/xyz': {
                target: 'xyz',
                parent: 'home'
            }
        }).subscribe(
            function(match) {
            }, function (nomatch) {
                $rootScope.isNavigated = true;
                var loc = nomatch.$link.fragment;
                subscribe_deeplink();
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    $location.path(loc);
                });
            }
        );
```

Now the deeplink works for my app on all the scenarios..

I want to know few things:

1. Is it a suggested way to go on above way?
2. Why onresume scenarios are not discussed on deeplink plugin. How you handle on resume scenarios. Am i missing something on the implementation

Answer (score 0):

At [Branch.io](https://branch.io) we actually hook into both `onDeviceReady` and `onResume` for this. The basic framework:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    Branch.initSession();
},
onResume: function() {
    Branch.initSession();
},
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
},
function DeepLinkHandler(data) {
    alert('Data from initSession: ' + data.data);
}
```

This obviously isn't a perfect correlation to the deep-link plugin, but might be useful as a reference point.

Shameless plug: you could also check out the [Branch.io](https://branch.io) deep link platform, since it does all of the same things along with a number additional benefits like deferred deep linking and attribution analytics.